# Ball around a boundary point of a set intersects set and its complement

Tags: real-analysis

The boundary $\partial E$ of a set $E$ is $\overline E$ \ $  int(E)$  where $\overline E$ is the closure of E which is the union of E and its limit points and   $int(E)$ is the set of interior point of $E$. I want to show that if $x \in \partial E$ then $B_r(x)$ intersect $E$ and $E^c$. In set we have,
$$\partial E =\{ x\in \overline E, x \notin int(E) \} $$
$x \notin int(E)$ means $B_r(x) \subsetneq E$ $\implies B_r(x) \bigcap E^c \neq \emptyset $.
$ \text{Secondly, } \partial E \subset E \implies x\in \partial E \implies B_r(x) \bigcap E \neq \emptyset $.
Therefore, the ball around a point of Boundary of a set intersects the set itself and its complement. Is this correct reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a metric space $(X,d_{X})$ and a subset $E\subseteq X$, we say that $x\in X$ is an interior point of $E$ iff there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_{r}(x)\subseteq E$.

We say that $x\in X$ is an exterior point of $E$ iff there exists $r > 0$ s.t. $B_{r}(x)\subseteq E^{c}$.

At last but not least, we say that $x\in X$ is a boundary point of $E$ iff $x$ is neither an interior point of $E$ nor an exterior point of $E$.

According to these definitions, $x\in\partial E$ iff for every $r > 0$, the relations $B_{r}(x)\not\subseteq E$ and $B_{r}(x)\not\subseteq E^{c}$ hold together.

These relations, by its turn, mean that $B_{r}(x)\cap E^{c}\neq\varnothing$ as well as $B_{r}(x)\cap E\neq\varnothing$ hold for every $r > 0$, which is exactly what you want.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I understand your proof but can you tell me what are the flaws in my proof